# What is the main uri for XTRF Home Portal?

Tags: api, etl, xtrf

I'd just want to use the getters from [Home Portal](https://xtrf.eu/xtrf-api-doc/home-api).

My company's dedicated url is like "mycompany.s.xtrf.eu", but it does not seems to be working for any API call, even with the good X-AUTH-ACCESS-TOKEN header.

I tried a get request on "mycompany.s.xtrf.eu/customers/XXX" but had a 404...

Please any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You're missing `/home-api/` so you should call `https://mycompany.s.xtrf.eu//home-api/{endpoint}`

Best,
B.

Comment: Manu thanks, it was a long time ago but it finally ok !

Answer (score 1):

The url has changed, you can use this url: https://xtrf.eu/api-doc/#/home-api

Comment: Effectively the url got changes